# Resizing a ScrollViewer containing many items is very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, resize, scrollviewer

I have a `ScrollViewer` containing a `StackPanel` that is filled with over 1000 items that each contain a bunch of other items. It performs like a champ at idle or when I actually scroll it. However, when I resize it or anything that causes it to resize (e.g. the containing top-level window), it gets really slow, freezes, and takes about 30 seconds to unfreeze and be resized.

I have discovered that setting `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden` or `ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled` before I resize makes it perfectly smooth. However, enabling and disabling `ScrollBarVisibility` takes around 5 seconds each, which, while better than waiting 30 seconds to resize, is still too long a wait.

What can I do to help gain performance in resizing a `StackPanel` in a `ScrollPanel` that contains many items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider switching to a listbox (I know, sounds weird, but hear me out).  The listbox uses a virtualizing stackpanel -- it manages how many controls are actually in memory, creating them as you scroll.

You can use a datatemplate to make each listbox item look like anything that you want.

(note, this is all assuming that you are displaying some sort of repeating data).

Comment: Two questions then: Would I get the same effect by just switching my `StackPanel` to a `VirtualizingStackPanel`? (if so, I've already tried and it didn't help); and: scrolling is smooth and does not lag. It's resizing the panel that lags, so if a `ListBox` is supposed to fix laggy scrolling, then I don't need it.

Comment: Also, controlling how many items are in memory would gain memory efficiency but probably would not be the cause of a speed gain like I need.

Comment: @SethCarnegie How hard would it be to like just test ListView?

Comment: @Blam I don't want to waste time on something that doesn't have any indication that it will work (unless I get a reply that indicates my assumptions are wrong).

Comment: @SethCarnegie But you have more key strokes into asking why than key stokes required to actually test.  I have a ListView with over 100,000 with absolutely no lag.

Comment: @Blam much to my surprise that actually helped with that problem. Now the problem is that you can select the elements of the list (which I don't want), and that scrolling the mouse wheel inside the `ListView` doesn't scroll the scrollbar that contains the `ListView`. If I change `IsHitTestVisible` on the `ListView` then the scroll wheel works and you can't select items of the list any more (which is good) but items in the list no longer receive mouse messages. Any idea how to remedy that?

Comment: @SethCarnegie Yes but do I have to prove it to you before you will try it.  And do I at least get a thanks?  And are you going to a least up vote this answer?

Comment: @Blam actually it turned out that `ListBox` did not fix the problem; it enables vertical resizing but not horizontal sizing to be lag-free. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @SethCarnegie to answer the questions in your comments, I expected this to help because by reducing the number of controls that were "live", there would have been fewer responders to the Measure event -- less code running, so it should be faster.  I'm not sure why you still have horizontal perf problems.  You might survey how many elements you have that would need to remeasure for a horizontal size change -- do you have content that is set to fill horizontally that doesn't need to?

Comment: @JMarsch actually I was just doing virtualisation wrong (I was adding elements directly to the container instead of binding `ItemsSource` and one or two other things that were  preventing virtualisation) so I remarked this as the correct answer.